# INET TCPSocket Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet, tcpsocket

I want to establish a TCP connection from my application in Omnet++ to an external server.

This is my sample code

```
inet::TCPSocket mysocket;
        mysocket.connect(inet::L3Address("192.168.12.226"),10000);
        EV<< "Socket connection" <<endl;
        cPacket * msg = new cPacket("solve");
        msg->setByteLength(1024);  // 1K
        mysocket.send(msg);
        mysocket.close();
```

This code compile, but when I run my application this error appears

**SetOutputGate() must be invoked before socket can be used**

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiebW.png)

The example code in the TCPSocket.h is very similar.

I don't understand this error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add:

```
mysocket.setOutputGate(gate("tcpOut"));
```

Comment: I use that function, but **tcpOut** should be an output gate in my ned file (pc2.ned in my example).

Comment: I defined a gate, to use it in the **setOutputGate** function, but it must be connected to another gate. That is my new problem, Where should I connect that gate to establish or use a TCP connection to external server or another computer?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: First of all, your TCP app has to inherit from `ITCPApp` (look at `inet\src\inet\applications\tcpapp\TCPEchoApp.ned`). Second, you should use `StandardHost`. Do you use it? You don't need to manually connect `tcpOut` and `tcpIn` to a network layer, because `StandardHost` will do it automatically. The only thing you should do is to set the number and type of TCP application in `omnetpp.ini`. Look at example `inet\examples\inet\ber\omnetpp.ini`.